# The name 'grdViewPersonnel' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error:
The name 'grdViewPersonnel' does not exist in the current context

```
public partial class frmViewPersonnel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            // Declare the DataSet
            dsPersonnel myDataSet = new dsPersonnel();

            // Fill the dataset with what is returned from the function
            myDataSet = clsDataLayer.GetPersonnel(Server.MapPath("PayrollSystem_DB.mdb"));

            // Set the DataGrid to the DataSource based on the table
            grdViewPersonnel.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["tblPersonnel"];

            //  Bind the DataGrid
            grdViewPersonnel.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your .aspx file have a `GridView` object named `grdViewPersonnel`?

Comment: @drdwilcox:  Thanks, I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would bet that the error isn't happening here? Maybe in the designer.cs file?

Answer (score 0):

Examin your code, if your GridView is really named `grdViewPersonnel`. Maybe you mistyped or it is declared later.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the gridview in the designer page is actually named `grdViewPersonnel`?